# drawing other pixels in java

Tags: java, graphics, pixel

I am trying to draw each pixel on the frame but I cannot work out how to draw the next pixel, it only shows one pixel drawn, plz help.
I do not know how to achieve this would someone edit this code so that it draws the pixels in the adjacent coordinates plz.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

   public class MyDrawPixel extends Frame {

      public Point mypoint = new Point();      
      public static void drawPixel(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size, Paint color)
     {
         Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
         Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, size, size);   
         ga.setPaint(color);
         ga.draw(circle);
         ga.setPaint(color);
         ga.fill(circle);
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        drawPixel(g, mypoint.x, mypoint.y, 1, Color.black);
     }


  public static void main(String args[])
  {    

      MyDrawPixel frame = new MyDrawPixel();    
      frame.mypoint.x = 43;
      frame.mypoint.y = 43;
      MyDrawPixel frame1 = new MyDrawPixel();    
      frame1.mypoint.x = 44;
      frame1.mypoint.y = 44;
      MyDrawPixel frame2 = new MyDrawPixel();    
      frame2.mypoint.x = 45;
      frame2.mypoint.y = 45;
      MyDrawPixel frame3 = new MyDrawPixel();    
      frame3.mypoint.x = 46;
      frame3.mypoint.y = 46;
      MyDrawPixel frame4 = new MyDrawPixel();    
      frame4.mypoint.x = 47;
      frame4.mypoint.y = 47;

      frame.addWindowListener(
      new WindowAdapter()
      {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
         {
            System.exit(0);
         }
      }
      );

       frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating 5 frames and displaying only one. What you need to do is create 1 frame and display it correctly.

You can use `repaint()` to refresh the screen, then just change the attributes between the repaints if you want to move a single dot around.

Or even better, find a proper tutorial about custom painting, your code is quite horrible.